# GitLab - Unable to run gitlab-ctl pg-upgrade

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

Here is what I execute:

```
armegon@codescarsgaming:~$ sudo gitlab-ctl pg-upgrade
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/lib/gitlab_ctl/util.rb:50:in `parse_json_file': Attributes not found in /opt/gitlab/embedded/nodes/codescarsgaming.json, has reconfigure been run yet? (GitlabCtl::Errors::NodeError)
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/lib/gitlab_ctl/util.rb:65:in `get_node_attributes'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/lib/gitlab_ctl/util.rb:104:in `roles'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/pg-upgrade.rb:147:in `block in load_file'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:204:in `block in add_command_under_category'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:746:in `run'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/bin/omnibus-ctl:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:25:in `load'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:25:in `<main>'
armegon@codescarsgaming:~$
```

Here is the contents of that file:

```
armegon@codescarsgaming:~$ sudo cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/nodes/codescarsgaming.json
{
  "name": "codescarsgaming"
}armegon@codescarsgaming:~$
```

The whole thing happened as a problem when I ran this command to upgrade:

```
apt-get install  gitlab-ce=16.0.1-ce.0
```

When I run reconfigure here is what I get:

```
[2023-06-02T16:23:58+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash_hide_env[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 20) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:110:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:96:in `method_missing'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:115:in `configure_database'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:110:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:96:in `method_missing'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:115:in `configure_database'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  ----
Ran "bash"  returned 1
```

Why am I unable to upgrade postgresql ? What can I do to fix it?